# How to combine these 2 json-like files?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have file1.txt with following contents;

```
[
  {
    "SERIAL": "124584",
    "X": "30024.1",
  },
  {
    "SERIAL": "114025",
    "X": "14006.2",
  }
]
```

I have file2.txt with following contents;

```
[
  {
    "SERIAL": "344588",
    "X": "48024.1",
  },
  {
    "SERIAL": "255488",
    "X": "56006.2",
  }
]
```

I want to combine the 2 files into single file `output.txt` that looks like this;

```
[
  {
    "SERIAL": "124584",
    "X": "30024.1",
  },
  {
    "SERIAL": "114025",
    "X": "14006.2",
  },
  {
    "SERIAL": "344588",
    "X": "48024.1",
  },
  {
    "SERIAL": "255488",
    "X": "56006.2",
  },  
]
```

The tricky part is the [] at the end of each individual file.

I am using python v3.7

Comment: What generates these files? It wouldn't take much to make them *actual* JSON, rather than JSON-like.

Comment: @chepner, good point. Let me study.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly to be JSON compliant, you may remove all the trailing commas (ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Trailing_commas)

Then you can use the following code:

```py
import json

with open("file1.txt") as f1:
   d1 = json.load(f1)

with open("file2.txt") as f2:
   d2 = json.load(f2)

d3 = d1 + d2
with open("output.txt", "w") as out:
   json.dump(d3, out)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution to read content from file and then append them.

```
from ast import literal_eval

with open("/home/umesh/Documents/text1.txt", "r") as data
   first_file_data = data.read()

with open("/home/umesh/Documents/text2.txt", "r") as data:
   second_file_data = data.read()

first_file_data = literal_eval(first_file_data)
second_file_data = literal_eval(second_file_data)

for item in second_file_data:
  first_file_data.append(item)

print(first_file_data)
```

OUTPUT

```
[{'SERIAL': '124584', 'X': '30024.1'},{'SERIAL': '114025', 'X': '14006.2'},{'SERIAL': '344588', 'X': '48024.1'},{'SERIAL': '255488', 'X': '56006.2'}]
```

[text file content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WDvMM.png)

Answer (score 1):

This solves your problem

```
import ast
import json


with open('file1.txt') as f:
   data = ast.literal_eval(f.read())


with open('file2.txt') as f:
    data2 = ast.literal_eval(f.read())

data.extend(data2)
print(data)

with open('outputfile', 'w') as fout: # write to a file
    json.dump(data, fout)
```

OUTPUT:

```
[{'SERIAL': '124584', 'X': '30024.1'}, {'SERIAL': '114025', 'X': '14006.2'}, {'SERIAL': '344588', 'X': '48024.1'}, {'SERIAL': '255488', 'X': '56006.2'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Since both of the content of the files are lists you can concatenate them together as following

```
file1 = [{'SERIAL': '124584', 'X': '30024.1'}, {'SERIAL': '114025', 'X': '14006.2'}]
file2 = [{'SERIAL': '344588', 'X': '48024.1'}, {'SERIAL': '255488', 'X': '56006.2'}]

totals = file1 + file2
```

Result

```
[{'SERIAL': '124584', 'X': '30024.1'},
 {'SERIAL': '114025', 'X': '14006.2'},
 {'SERIAL': '344588', 'X': '48024.1'},
 {'SERIAL': '255488', 'X': '56006.2'}]
```